# ERROR: cannot find symbol variable toast

Tags: android, android-studio

I copied the following code from a tutorial but it shows 4 errors, all same : cannot find symbol variable toast. I searched a lot for any solution but was unable to find any. Following is the MainActivity.java file of my code-

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button checkIntrnetButton;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        checkIntrnetButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.checkInternetButton);
        checkIntrnetButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                checkConnection();
            }
        });
    }
    protected boolean isOnline() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public void checkConnection(){
        if(isOnline()){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You are connected to Internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You are not connected to Internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `import android.widget.Toast;`

Comment: You asked right question. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just import  **`import android.widget.Toast;`** it will work

Like this

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.widget.Toast;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the import.

Some basic steps after removing the import, if those errors appear:

- Clean your build, then rebuild
- Make sure there are no errors or typos in your XML files
- Make sure your resource names consist of [a-z0-9.]. Capitals or
  symbols are not allowed for some reason.
- Perform a Gradle sync (via Tools > Android > Sync Project with Gradle
  Files)

and then reimport auto, make sure you have all the old import plus this one : `import android.widget.Toast;`

Answer (score 0):

import  `import android.widget.Toast;` it should work. just hover over error and follow hint :P

If it still shows same error, restart your Android studio. select `File` => `Invalidate cashes And restart` => `Invalidate and Restart`